# Training Set, Validation Set and Test Set for Time Series

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, lstm

I have monthly time series data on stock prices from January 1990 to August 2023. I tend to use *walk-forward* validation to compare the forecasting performance of *ARIMA* and *LSTM* models on this time series. I split the time series as follows:

**Sub-training**: January 1990 to December 2020

**Training**: January 1990 to December 2021

**Validation**: January 2021 to December 2021

**Test**: January 2022 to August 2023

For the *LSTM* part, 9 models (3 values for the number of units and 3 values for the number of lags) are going to be trained and a forecasting model will be selected using the following steps:

1. Training the 9 LSTM models on the **sub-training** set.
2. Evaluating the performance of the models on the **validation set**.
3. Selecting the model with the minimum **validation RMSE**.
4. Building the selected model on the **training set**.
5. Implementing a *walk-forward* forecast for **test set** using the selected model and calculating the **test RMSE**

I hope I have been clear enough and I would appreciate your feedback on whether the split sets and the above steps I have chosen are reasonable.

Comment: At first sight it looks reasonable to me, but runs the risk of overfitting to 2021 validation data.  You could do more validation: have several sub-training sets (as many as possible), each starting in January 1990 and ending in December xxxx, and associated with a validation set January xxxx+1 to December xxxx+1, train all the models on each sub-training set and look at the sum of validation MSEs across the validation sets.

Comment: @Henry: I appreciate your helpful comment. Is there any problem with the proportion of split sets? For instance, the test set includes 20 observations which is about 5 percent of the whole data. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: More test data is good, but you need to balance this against losing training data.  You have quite a lot of training data, so you could for example have three and a bit  test sets: 2020, 2021, 2022, and part of 2023 with your training data 1990 to 2019.  With your single chosen model (and any hyperparameters) from the validation process, you could train it on 1990-2019 and test against 2020, train it on 1990-2020 and test it on 2021,  train it on 1990-2021 and test it on 2022, and  train it on 1990-2022 and test it on part of 2023.  You would see performance in the Covid and Ukraine periods.

Comment: Is this a type of walk-forward or totally different approach? If it's different, then do I need to apply walk-forward? Because the final model has to be compared with a final model of ARIMA which is obtained in the same way. How can I compare the performance of two models?

Comment: It is still an attempt to "[walk-forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walk_forward_optimization)" using recent unseen data as a substitute for future data, just doing more testing, and you could so something similar with your ARIMA model.  But clearly if you are comparing the two, you need to apply the same test on the same unseen data (past or future) to both.

Comment: Therefore, I can use 4 sub-training sets and 4 corresponding validation sets. For example 1990 to 2017 as sub-traing1 and 2018 as validation1, 1990 to 2018 as sub-traing2 and 2019 as validation2, 1990 to 2019 as sub-traing3 and 2020 as validation3, and finally 1990 to 2020 as sub-traing4 and 2021 as validation4. The test set still going to be 2022 and part of 2023. The best LSTM model and best ARIMA model both will be used for a one-step-ahead forecast on the test set to mimic the real-world scenario. Is this the right approach?

Comment: It seems reasonable to me

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to answer my questions. It really helped me to understand the issue. Thanks again.